# Prove that a unique linear map exists with these conditions (or not!)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So...I have to either prove or deny that there exists a unique linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ where:

$$\ f(1,1)=(2,6)$$
$$\ f(-1,1)=(2,1)$$
$$\ f(2,7)=(5,3)$$

I know that if, for example, we remove the third condition it can easily be proven that  $$\ (1,1),(-1,1)$$
are linearly independent and so they form a basis on $\mathbb{R}^2$, making such a linear map unique.

But now I have three conditions, where $$\ (1,1),(-1,1),(2,7)$$ are, as far as I can see, also linearly independent by checking their determinants in pairs. But how come there can be a basis on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with three vectors? Is this possible or is it a "trick" question?

Comment: Do you mean "linear map" instead of "linear combination"?

Comment: Sorry - Yes, I edited it now. I sometimes forget about it and do a literal translation from my mother language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check linear independence of a set of three (or more) vectors by checking them pairwise. That is like saying $6$ and $10$ share a factor, and $10$ and $15$ share a factor, and $6$ and $15$ share a factor, so $6$, $10$, and $15$ all share a common factor (they don't). And in fact, no three vectors in a two-dimensional vector space such as $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be linearly independent. So it must be that $(1,1)$, $(-1,1)$, and $(2,7)$ are linearly dependent. Now you need to find a way to write one of them as a linear combination of the others, and see if the three conditions you were given are consistent or not.

Comment: Thanks! So indeed they are linearly dependent (example: (1,1)=2/9*(-1,1)+1/9*(2,7), does this mean that I can "reduce" the basis to any of these two vectors just like that?, I guess there is a condition that needs to be met for their images?

Comment: I don't think that linear combination works. $\frac{2}{9}(-1,1)+\frac{1}{9}(2,7)=\left(-\frac{2}{9},\frac{2}{9}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{9},\frac{7}{9}\right) = (0,1)$. In any case, if you've written $(1,1)=\alpha(-1,1)+\beta(2,7)$, then by properties of linear maps you should have $f(1,1)=\alpha f(-1,1)+\beta f(2,7)$. This is the condition you will have to check (after you've written one of these vectors as a linear combination of another).

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it, it was a simple check for the properties...and indeed it was wrong(α=-5/9,β=2/9)